# Using a ComboBox as filter

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have made a program that is a kind of a wiki, but in a program. I've added lots of pictureBoxes, and I have 3 filters to sort those pictureBoxes: ROLE, ATTACK TYPE and NAME.
What I'd like to do is, like, if you select the Attack Type RANGED it disables the other pictureBoxes that has a different Attack Type than RANGED.

I've tried comparing each Hero (I've made a different class for it) with a timer, but I didn't know how to do it.

I also tried this

```
if(comboBox1.Text == "RANGED") { //do stuff }
```

But I don't know how could I access all of the heroes inside an array I made, and check if they have atkType = RANGED.

My Hero.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public struct Hero
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Role; /* carry, disabler, lane support, initiator, jungler, support, durable, nuker, pusher, escape */
        public string atkType; /* melee or ranged */
        public string Type; /* strength, agility or intelligence */
        public string imgName;

        public Hero(string name, string role, string atktype, string type, string imgname)
        {
            Name = name;
            Role = role;
            atkType = atktype;
            Type = type;
            imgName = imgname;
        }

        public static Hero[] heroes = new Hero[] { 
            new Hero() {Name = "test", Role = "", atkType = "Melee", Type = "Strength", imgName = "test" }
        };
    }
}
```

I've managed to get the filter working, but now, there's only a problem: I can't dispose (images wont unload) the current loaded images and can't load new ones.
What I tried:

```
 if (melee == false && ranged == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Hero.heroes.Length; i++)
            {
                imgs[i].Load("http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/" + Hero.heroes[i].imgName + "_sb.png");
                comboBox3.Items.Add(Hero.heroes[i].Name);
                //imgs[i].MouseHover += displayInfo(i);
            }

        }
        if (ranged == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Hero.heroes.Length && Hero.heroes[i].atkType.Contains("Ranged"); i++)
            {
                imgs[i].Image.Dispose();
                imgs[i].Load("http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/" + Hero.heroes[i].imgName + "_sb.png");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't dispose" of the images? An error, nothing happens, a memory leak...?

Comment: well, the images aren't being unloaded.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the image in the `PictureBox`? What should it look like? You could simplify this question substantially, since it doesn't seem to be about the combo box, only about changing the display based on the value in the combo box.

Comment: kind of, i have like ~105 pictureboxes and i want to unload them and only load those whose have atkType = ranged

Answer (score 0):

The code could be something like this:

```
if(cmb.text=="goofy")
    //Code
else if(cmb.text=="mars")
   //Other code
else 
   //BLA BLA
```

Comment: Yes yes, I was thinking of this but, I forgot to mention, I have a Hero class containing strings such as atkType for attack type. So how could I access the Hero array (which is heroes) and check if the atkType is RANGED?

Comment: @AlexandreOliveira of course if the Array is public you can have a direct access to the Array.

Comment: would I need a loop to check the condition inside the array?

Comment: Yes you can use a foreach loop it's more easy to understand

Comment: alright so I did different loops inside a timer, but now I'm stuck, I can't make the program delete the previously loaded images and load new ones.